# ERROR JDBCExceptionReporter:78 - Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'

Tags: spring

Using tomcat 7.0.100 and spring 3.0 with mysql 5.7,jdk 1.7 whenever I define docBase in server.xml its throwing error:

2023-09-11 13:27:10 ERROR JDBCExceptionReporter:78 - Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'2023-09-11 13:27:10 WARN  SettingsFactory:109 - Could not obtain connection metadatajava.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'

Without docbase defined, its working properly in tomcat.

I have defined mysql connection in meta-inf/context.xml file as

```
 <Resource 
    auth="Container" 
    name="jdbc/NRIFT" 
    type="javax.sql.DataSource" 

    maxActive="100" 
    maxIdle="30" 
    maxWait="10000"
    
    driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"             
    url="jdbc:mysql://x.x.x.x/yy?autoReconnect=true&amp;useSSL=false" 
    username="yy"
    password="yy"
 />
```

In web.xml it is defined as

```
<resource-ref>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/NRIFT</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>
```

In spring-servlet.xml it is defined as

```
<bean id="myDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/NRIFT"/>
        <property name="resourceRef" value="true"/>
    </bean>
```

any help is appreciated.